# Radio frequency spectrum analyzer for Raspberry Pi

Tags: rtl-sdr

I am doing research for a new project and would like to poll the community for any advice.

I want to build a spectrum analyzer on the Pi that will log frequencies and the power level they are at.

I was looking at the SDR USB antenna on Adafruit, but all of the tutorials paired it with a screen/GUI. For my project, I do not need any visual indicators, just text logging.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: How good is your Python? [Adafruit's source code on Github](https://github.com/adafruit/FreqShow) looks quite well put together - particularly note model.py/def get_data(self):, which returns FFTs of sampled radio signals. It may be easier just to tear that to bits than to source a suitable package.